# I cannot click capture button to capture virtual machine image

Tags: image, azure, capture, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

[image: click to see the picture which shows what happens]

I cannot click Capture (2nd last button "캡처" in Korean) button in Azure portal.
All other virtual machines are same to this situation.

Yesterday, I captured image by clicking that button, but today I cannot click it.
Could you let me know why this happens and how I can solve this problem???

One more question!
this is error log
Provisioning failed. OS Provisioning for VM 'master0' did not finish in the allotted time. However, the VM guest agent was detected running. This suggests the guest OS has not been properly prepared to be used as a VM image (with CreateOption=FromImage). To resolve this issue, either use the VHD as is with CreateOption=Attach or prepare it properly for use as an image:
 * Instructions for Windows: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-upload-image/ 
 * Instructions for Linux: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/. OSProvisioningTimedOut

I use a Linux machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You need stop your VM firstly. Stop the VM by usgin Azure Portal.

2.Create your VM image on Azure Portal.

[image]

[image]

3.Create new VMs by using the image.

[image]

Also, you could use PowerShell to capture image, more information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-capture-image).

Comment: Can I ask one more?
even though i made image file well, but I failed gerating a vm from image.
provisioning things issue.

Comment: Hi  do you execut `sudo waagent -deprovision+user` ?

Comment: if i execute "sudo waagent -deprovision+user", my ssh key disappear(it succeed though..), so I cannot use ambari to install a spark cluster among VMs